# Direct notification mechanisms?

Tags: discussion, edits, review, notifications, new-users

While doing a review of Suggested Edits today on SO, I noticed that a certain low rep user was *adding* the text *"Thanks in Advance..."* to the end of every single question he edited.

In my opinion, adding a tagline to somebody else's question is very inappropriate and completely unnecessary, so I cast a "reject" vote.

My question is not how to handle this, nor is my question about reporting it.

Luckily, in this case, a moderator was already reviewing these same edits and also rejecting them.  Even though these edits were ultimately rejected, a few "approve" votes were also cast.

Is there a way that SO, either automatically or via moderator, will directly notify this user of his misguided actions?  Otherwise, how will he know to immediately stop adding *"Thanks in Advance..."* to every single question he edits?

<s>Thanks in Advance...</s>

Comment: Leave a constructive comment in the rejection message or on one of the user's posts pointing at the relevant Meta post. Worked for me in the past.

Comment: This user successfully edited 41 questions with _"Thanks in Advance"_ on at least half. I randomly checked and most of his edits were since removed and/or corrected. However, I found a few intact, corrected them, and left a polite comment on one.

Comment: Great @sparky. Thanks for the work. Let's hope he picks it up. Looking at some of the edits, far more should have been rejected than actually happened. Which in turn would have likely stopped the user as well. It's a shame reviews are still so difficult to get right.

Comment: One of the possible solutions suggested at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209060/could-users-receive-notifications-for-further-edits-rollbacks-on-their-edits/284326#284326

Comment: More examples: [***adding*** *"Kindly guide me for this"*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24536369) and [***adding*** *"thanks in advance.*"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24547917)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There will be no automatic notification.  If enough of his posts are rejected then he will be banned from suggesting edits for a period of time, and further attempts at suggesting edits will result in a message indicating he is edit banned and linking him to his profile where he can see the reason previous edits were rejected.

If you want, you can post a comment on one of the posts he edited; an @ reply can be posted to someone who edited a post (even though there won't be auto-completion) and it WILL send a notification to that user's inbox.

Comment: It will be good to have automated notifications, when edits rejected/ reverted

Answer (score 0):

Moderators have the ability to send private messages directly to a user for behavior they decide is egregiously bad. I wouldn't be surprised if that has already happened here.

Anyone, you or a moderator, can also leave a comment regarding the edits below one of the user's posts.* If any of the edits went through, you can notify the editor by commenting on the edited post, too. (Also, be sure to revert the edit.) Be polite, and ideally, link to "further reading" info either here on Meta or in the FAQ.

---

*If you do so, it would be nice if you came back and deleted it a few days later.

Comment: Moderator messages are reserved for particularly bad behavior and should *not* be used for something like this.